# Form element is not rendered

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I am trying to render the form element below in *telisim* module but it's not working, no output (see the screenshot). [image]

The telisim.module file looks as follow:

```
//hook_menu

function telisim_menu() {
    $items['simcodes'] = array(
    'title' => 'SIM CODES',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('telisim_examples'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
* Implements hook_element_info().
*/

function telisim_element_info() {
  return array(
    'telisim_notepad' => array(
      '#input' => TRUE,
      '#process' => array('porta_teslisim_notepad_process_callback'),
      '#theme_wrappers' => array('telisim_inline_form_element'),
    ),
  );
}

function porta_teslisim_notepad_process_callback($element, &$form_state, $complete_form) {

 $element['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // Normal FAPI field definitions, except that #value is defined.
  $element['areacode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 3,
    '#maxlength' => 3,
    '#value' => $element['#value']['areacode'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '(',
    '#suffix' => ')',
  );
  $element['prefix'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 3,
    '#maxlength' => 3,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#value' => $element['#value']['prefix'],
  );
  $element['extension'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 4,
    '#maxlength' => 4,
    '#value' => $element['#value']['extension'],
  );

   return $element;

  }

  function _telisim_element_theme() {
  return array(
    'telisim_inline_form_element' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
      'file' => 'telisim.module',
    ),
    'telisim_checkbox' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
      'file' => 'telisim.module',
    ),
  );
}


function telisim_examples($form, &$form_state){

  $form['a_form_example_element_discrete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'telisim_notepad',
    '#title' => t('Discrete phone number'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get(
      'form_example_element_discrete',
      array(
        'areacode' => '999',
        'prefix' => '999',
        'extension' => '9999',
      )
    ),
    '#description' => t('A phone number : areacode (XXX), prefix (XXX) and extension (XXXX).'),
  );

   dsm($form);
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1) Your hook_theme() implementation is named incorrectly, meaning it will never be called. This:

```
_telisim_element_theme()
```

Should be this:

```
telisim_theme()
```

2) You haven't implemented `theme_telisim_inline_form_element()`, so there is no HTML for the form element to render.

You need to create this function, and output the relevant HTML for your form element inside the function.

Comment: Should just be `function telisim_theme()` to stay in line with all the others hooks, but yeah, this basically